# Radius of footprint vs altitude: math equation

Tags: footprint, satellite, beamforming

[image]

I want to compare footprint size/beam size of satellite and plot “radius of footprint vs. altitude” variation. ( my main reference( see above) is 3GPPTR38_821/Solutions for {NR} to support non-terrestrial networks {(NTN)})

I have seen [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55163/how-to-compute-footprintsize-of-beam-of-sat-system) a discussion “How to compute footprint(size) of beam of sat.system?”  In the equation they use the size of antennas is required. This information I don’t have.

I believe, the radius shrinks when the altitude descents, but I want to have a visualization and mathematical proof.

Does anyone know what mathematical expression I can use for my simulation?

PS.  I want to use the cone's footprint calculation equation. I fix an angle and use *sin* or *cos* to compute ½ of the footprint

[image]

Can I choose any angle I want?

Comment: *Can I choose any angle I want?* <-- no, you need to know the beam width (which you say you don't have).

Comment: @Andyaka without antenna parameters is it not possible I think :( is there any other methods how I can make the same computation as it is given in the table ?